# Audio processing in C# or C++

Tags: c#, c++, wav, audio-processing

I would like to create an application that uses AI techniques and allows the user to record a part of a song and then tries to find that song in a database of wav files.

I would have liked to use some already existing libraries for the audio processing part. So, could you recommend any libraries in C# which can read a wav file, get input from microphone, have some audio filters (low pass, high pass, FFT etc) and maybe have the ability to plot the audio signal as well.

I would prefer to develop in C#, but if there aren't good libraries for audio processing, I guess I could work in C++ as well. As far as I know, Mathlab already has the above mentioned functionalities, but I can't use it in my application.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701240/writing-an-audio-player-in-c/2701258#2701258

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to read and record audio signal, I recommend this lib

NAudio: https://naudio.codeplex.com

But if you need a signal processing support, I think this one is much better

CSCORE: https://github.com/filoe/cscore

Comment: Why do you recommend these libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [FMOD](http://www.fmod.org/) for example, not sure if it can do everything you need though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any publicly available "audio fingerprint / matching" libraries that can deal with short snippets. There's a [libfooid project](http://code.google.com/p/libfooid/) but I think it requires you to record the whole song. Also, the audio device interaction is not part of that library. You have to use another library for recording audio data.